# For an integrally closed domain $A$ with finite integral extension $B$ and $\alpha\in B$, is it true that $m_\alpha\in A[x]$?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

This is our setup: Let $A$ be an integrally closed domain with fraction field $K$, let $L$ be a finite separable extension of $K$, and let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. Fix the following notation: for $\alpha\in L$, we let $\chi_{L/K,\alpha}(x)\in K[x]$ denote the characteristic polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$,and let $m_{L/K,\alpha}(x)\in K[x]$ denote the minimal polynomial, both of which are assumed to be monic.

Then it is a fact (proved using Gauss's lemma and some linear algebra) that if $A$ is a UFD, then we have the following equivalence, for any $\alpha\in L$:

1. $\alpha\in B$
2. $m_{L/K,\alpha}(x)\in A[x]$
3. $\chi_{L/K,\alpha}(x)\in A[x]$

However, does this equivalence still hold in the case where $A$ is an arbitrary integrally closed domain, or if it is a Dedekind domain (a common setup in algebraic number theory)? Do we have a weaker equivalence?

Comment: Aren't the coefficients of the charpoly and minpoly integral over $A$?

Comment: This result is true for all integrally closed domains.

Comment: How do we show that the coefficients of the minimal polynomial are integral over $A$?

Comment: The coefficients are symmetric polynomials in the conjugates of $\alpha$, all of which are integral over $A$, if we assume 1. Thus 2. and 3. follow.

Comment: This question is the reason I do not understand why some textbooks use the Gauss lemma-argument to show this in the case $A=\mathbb Z$. You just lose some low-hanging fruits by doing this.